# Ambiguity of Pseudo Forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity, aether

Suppose we have an observer standing still in an inertial frame of reference. We will consider a scenario where there are no real forces acting on them in the inertial frame.

If we define a non-inertial, accelerating, frame with respect to the observer's inertial frame, we find that the observer must feel a non-zero pseudo-force acting on them as measured in the non-inertial frame, yielding a contradiction.

We could resolve this paradox by saying that any REAL acceleration is with respect to a **physical background medium** and that **arbitrary** coordinate transformations are **NOT applicable**, if they are to disregard such a "background medium."

But what properties does such a "background medium" entail? Is my reasoning valid? This line of reasoning is similar to those of the "aether" but where we consider only accelerations as absolute, and not velocity.

Comment: What is the contradiction here?

Comment: Depending on what accelerating frame of reference I choose, we find different values for the experienced force. However, if we consider acceleration with respect to some background medium and not arbitrary coordinate transformations we yield physically meaningful results.

Comment: Your statements are not making sense. To begin with, the statement "In the inertial frame, the observer should feel no forces acting on them" is incorrect. The observer will can feel real forces. But an observer in an inertial frame does not experience pseudo forces. Pseudo forces are only experienced in non-inertial frames. After that statement, it gets muddier and muddier.

Comment: I am referring to physically measurable forces, as measured by an accelerometer, and (knowing the mass of course.) I am asking whether or not is it necessary to invoke absolute space to resolve this paradox.

Comment: There is no contradiction: in Newtonian mechanics, velocity is relative while acceleration is absolute. There's absolutely no reason to expect all quantities to be relative or all quantities to be absolute. Different quantities can be different.

Comment: You might ask, if acceleration and velocity can be qualitatively different, how could we possibly have known that? By observing the real world.

Answer (score 1):

You do not see a difference in forces.  You see a difference in pseudoforces.

In both cases the observe has exactly 0 forces on it.  However, in a non-inertial frame, we find that there is an acceleration on the object, which is basically the inverse of the non-inertial behavior of the frame in the first place.

The key to understanding these things is that *the equations of motion in a non-inertial frame are not the same as the equations of motion in an inertial frame*.  They are different.  Now it happens to be that, in your case, the difference between those two equations of motion looks like an acceleration, and if you multiply an acceleration by a mass, you get something that appears like a force, but is not a force.  It's just a difference in the equations of motion that happens to be numerically similar in form.

The thing that is "experienced" in this non-inertial frame is not a force, but rather a mathematical artifact of how motion should be thought of in that non-inertial frame.  The place where we start seeing real forces take part is when we have a constrainted observer (like an observer stuck to the wall of a rotating system).  In that case, the forces between the observer and the walls are real... but the "centrifugal force" is actually just a pseudoforce.  It's a mathematical oddity.

Now... expose a human observer to this situation, and our monkey brain does indeed have to process what is happening to it.  And our monkey brain may observe the pseudoforce as if it were a force... but that's mental processing, not the actual physical mathematics.

The only thing that's really 'special' about inertial frames is that they tend to have the simplest equations of motion to calculate.  But that's really the only thing that's special about them.  Each and every frame has its own equations of motion.

Answer (score 0):

Ya the observer is in the inertial frame so she won't experience any pseudo force.Only an observer in a non-inertial frame would experience a non-zero pseudo force. Non inertial frame itself means it's under acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

> We could resolve this paradox by saying that any REAL acceleration is
> with respect to a physical background medium

It is not necessary that the acceleration be related to a specific inertial frame. Any inertial frame is equally suitable.

Suppose an acceleration frame $O''$, a inertial frame $O$ and another inertial frame $O'$.

For $O'$ a point $\mathbf x$ in $O''$ follows (because it is accelerated) , $$\frac {\partial \mathbf x}{\partial t} = \mathbf f(t) \neq 0$$

For $O$, if $O'$ is travelling at velocity $\mathbf v$, the same point $\mathbf x$ in $O''$ follows

$$\frac {\partial (\mathbf x - \mathbf v t)}{\partial t} = \mathbf g(t) = \frac {\partial \mathbf x}{\partial t} - \mathbf v $$
because $\mathbf v$ is constant.

When both $O$ and $O'$ calculate the acceleration of $O''$ they differentiate $\mathbf f$ and $\mathbf g$, getting the same value, again because $\mathbf v$ is constant. And if the acceleration is the same, also the pseudo-forces.